How to get Bearer token from Authorize form in swaggerUI and openapi?
My open API has three types of authorizations.
The first one is OAth2. It worked wells.
The second one is basic authentication. This is also ok.
The third one is the Bearer token. This only keeps the token and shows "******" instead of a string after clicking authorize. They do not verify or check whether the token is valid.
I want to get the token and call authorization by my sell, but I can not find out how to get the token from SwingUI or the open API.
I tried using JS, but I could not get the token.
Does anyone know how to do this? or any suggestions?
